# Pass additional information to IBM Watson Machine Learning job and retrieve via python API

Tags: machine-learning, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, python-3.9, docplex

I've been using IBM CPLEX Optimization Studio to run Decision Optimization (DOCPLEX) models locally with python API. I have a bulk of temporal data (hourly time steps for 20 years) and I define and solve optimization problems for 24h windows. I can track the progress by incrementing a counter (e.g. `tqdm`) every time a new model is created.

Now I'm using IBM Watson Machine Learning with python API to deploy these models. I store both the DOCPLEX model and the window-splitting logic on the IBM Cloud. I'd like to keep it this way because I'd rather send 20x365x24 rows of data as a single job than make as many API calls (each model solves in much less time than it takes to post a job and retrieve results). I'd still like to track the progress but the only useful information in `job_details` is job status (e.g. queued/completed/failed).

**Is there a way to pass additional information, such as model number, to `job_details` from within the model? Or retrieve the logs while the job is running?**

I read the [API documentation](https://ibm-wml-api-pyclient.mybluemix.net/api.html) and went through the [notebook examples](https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/DO-Samples/tree/watson_studio_cloud/jupyter/Cloud%20Pak%20for%20Data%20v4.6.x) provided by IBM but failed to find such a use case.